# How to stop console to prompt the user during output, under gdb and octave?

Tags: bash, console, gdb, octave

I am using Kubuntu and its Konsole terminal. I have annoying behavior using different applications from console such as gdb or octave. The problem is following: the program outputs one screen of text and than stops, prompting me with double colon and waiting for me to press any key so that it can continue with the output. So if the output is big (for example 10000 iterations in octave which print some values) I have to click Enter numerous times until I get to the end of the output. I would like not to be prompt at all. I don't know if this is due to bash, Konsole application or a program in question (gdb or octave for example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the specific case of GNU Octave, you can turn off this behavior by running `more off` at the Octave prompt. You may want to add that line to your `.octaverc` file.

Comment: Yes, this does solve the problem in octave. I still need an answer for the gdb.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to repeat an input automatically, then `yes` is your solution :

```
$ yes | any_app_waiting_input
```

As default behaviour, yes print a "y". You can put an argument to `yes` if you want anything else, like newlines : `yes ""`

Comment: If it actually spawning a pager such as less, I am not sure this will help.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Jantio's answer, you can use can use `cat` as your pager by setting the `PAGER` environment variable:

For all commands:

```
export PAGER=cat
```

For a single command:

```
PAGER=cat git log
```

Comment: +1 Cool! Always learning new things, and this is very practical =)

Answer (score 1):

For GDB, you can use "**set pagination off**" to change this behavior. See [GDB Manual: Screen Size](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Screen-Size.html). I tend to toggle pagination on and off quite often as I use GDB.

Answer (score 0):

I think the output is being presented through a pager (ie. probably `less` or `more`).

One simple way to bypass this is to redirect the output using `cat`:

```
my_command | cat
```

Hope this helps =)